# Coordinate Vector in Orthonormal Basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the following statement correct?

> For some vector $\mathbf{v}$ in an inner product space and an orthonormal basis for that space $B=\{ \mathbf{b}_{1},\mathbf{b}_{2},\ldots,\mathbf{b}_{n} \}$, the coordinate vector $[\mathbf{v}]_{B}=\begin{bmatrix}
>            \langle\mathbf{v}{,}\;\mathbf{b}_{1}\rangle \\
>            \langle\mathbf{v}{,}\;\mathbf{b}_{2}\rangle \\
>            \vdots \\
>            \langle\mathbf{v}{,}\;\mathbf{b}_{n}\rangle
>          \end{bmatrix}$

My text book states this equation: $\mathbf{v}=\langle\mathbf{v}{,}\;\mathbf{b}_{1}\rangle\,\mathbf{b}_{1}+\cdots+\langle\mathbf{v}{,}\;\mathbf{b}_{2}\rangle\,\mathbf{b}_{2}$, but doesn't extend the idea to coordinate vectors. Is my statement correct?

Comment: What do you mean by coordinate vector here? I mean, your statement is just about expressing a vector $v$ as a linear combination of an orthonormal basis $\{b_1,\dots,b_n\}$. The components of $v$ with respect to this basis are the numbers $\langle v, b_i\rangle$. This holds for all vectors in your vector space.

Comment: Yes, this holds for all vectors in the space, but not any basis. Only an orthonormal basis. I guess my question was, does the notion of a coordinate vector in this context make sense, with the purpose to just assign the entries of v. I guess you answered this with your first question.